# EOF Error in Imaplib

Tags: python, eof, imaplib

I am programming a python applet that watches the unread count of the email boxes for my workplace, and ran into an EOF error when I try to use any imaplib methods after the applet sits idle for about 10 minutes. Everything works fine until the applet has been alive for more than 10 minutes.

Here is the relevant code for the imaplib object.

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)

def loginIMAP (imapObj):
    # Login to Helpdesk Google Apps Email account using encryption
    imapObj.login(base64.b64decode("usrEncryption"), base64.b64decode("pwdEncrytion"))
    return(getUnread(imapObj))

def closeIMAP (imapObj):
    imapObj.logout()


def getUnread (imapObj):
    # Check connection status OK
    try:   
        uc0 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", imapObj.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
        uc1 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", imapObj.status("A box 1", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
        uc2 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", imapObj.status("A box 2", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
    except:
        print "Shit's all disconnected n stuff"
        loginIMAP(conn)

    unreadCount = [(uc0-(uc1+uc2)),uc1,uc2]
    if unreadCount[0] < 0:
        unreadCount[0]=0
    return unreadCount
```

`usrEncryption` and `pwdEncryption` are just me masking the u/p so our helpdesk logins aren't all public.

When I try and call the `getUnread(conn)` after having the applet open for more than ten minues I get the following output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Projects\Check HD Box\checkHDBox.py", line 255, in OnRefresh
    unread = getUnread(conn)
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Projects\Check HD Box\checkHDBox.py", line 119, in getUnread
    uc0 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", imapObj.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Python\python2.7.2\lib\imaplib.py", line 710, in status
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox, names)
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Python\python2.7.2\lib\imaplib.py", line 1070, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Python\python2.7.2\lib\imaplib.py", line 899, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: STATUS => socket error: EOF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Projects\Check HD Box\checkHDBox.py", line 255, in OnRefresh
    unread = getUnread(conn)
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Projects\Check HD Box\checkHDBox.py", line 119, in getUnread
    uc0 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", imapObj.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Python\python2.7.2\lib\imaplib.py", line 710, in status
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox, names)
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Python\python2.7.2\lib\imaplib.py", line 1070, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Jamin'sApps\Development\Python\python2.7.2\lib\imaplib.py", line 859, in _command
    raise self.abort('socket error: %s' % val)
imaplib.abort: socket error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

The exception block doesnt really seem to work for the problem, which is what I really need help with. So how do I keep this connection alive and kicking?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it's timing out.  But by default there is no timeout set on the `socket` in imaplib, so maybe it's Gmail doing it?  Do you get different results with a different SMTP server?

Answer (score 17):

You need to reconnect by re-initialize class, not just login, using

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
```

A complete example:

```
while True:
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SERVER)
    r, d = imap.login(ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
    assert r == 'OK', 'login failed'
    try:
        # do things with imap
    except imap.abort, e:
        continue
    imap.logout()
    break
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the 'e' for in the exception?

Comment: `e` is just for represent an exception instance, that you can do `log.error(str(e))` in the `except` block

Answer (score 7):

I managed to integrate cxase's into a custom imap class that took care of all my problems. Here is the code for anyone reading this:

```
class IMAPConnection():

    def __init__(self):
        self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)

    def login (self):
        # Login to Helpdesk Google Apps Email account using encryption
        self.imap.login(base64.b64decode("username"), base64.b64decode("password"))

    def logout (self):
        self.imap.logout()

    def getUnread (self):
        # Check connection status OK
        try:   
            uc0 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", self.imap.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
            uc1 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", self.imap.status("A box 1", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
            uc2 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", self.imap.status("A box 2", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
        except imap.abort:

            # Reinstantiate connection and login
            self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
            self.login()

            # Retry unread update block
            uc0 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", self.imap.status("INBOX", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
            uc1 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", self.imap.status("A box 1", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))
            uc2 = int(re.search("UNSEEN (\d+)", self.imap.status("A box 2", "(UNSEEN)")[1][0]).group(1))

        # Is the Helpdesk Negative? Hell no it's not.
        unreadCount = [(uc0-(uc1+uc2)),uc1,uc2]
        if unreadCount[0] < 0:
            unreadCount[0]=0
        return unreadCount
```

Comment: do you know thr DRY role?
But btw - I 'plussed' your answer )